# Installing ubuntu on lenovo desktop alongside windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I am planning to buy a desktop from lenovo. The desktop has windows 10 pre built. I just wanted to know if it is possible to install ubuntu alongside win 10 in lenovo desktop? Did anyone tried that? If then any link of the steps of install is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: "I am planning to buy a desktop from lenovo" What are its specs ? I guess it is just a standard X86_64 Intel/AMD thing, so yes you can. You would be alot better off Googling the different hardware for know issues than asking such a vague question here. Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason why this shouldn't be possible. Please refer to [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) in order to install Ubuntu alongside Windows.